# Do UWP Console Apps work on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: uwp, console-application, windows-10-iot-core

I've tried getting them to work, but I haven't had much success. I'd like to, really.

I want to be able to run these apps on Windows 10 IoT but I can't seem to run or debug them on RPI Build 17763.316

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/06/06/c-console-uwp-applications/#owRRo3EJKkEkiAkS.97

https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2018/06/06/writing-console-apps-with-uwp/

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UWP console App which created from the template can not run on Windows IoT Core.

Windows IoT Core supports certain traditional Win32 app types such as Win32 Console Apps, NT Services and .net core console app. If the console app is traditional win32 app, it apparently only supports in C++. But if you want to develop a console app with C#, you can use .net core console, in this way, you need to run the command to publish the app for ARM, and then copy the release folder to device.

```
dotnet publish -r win10-arm
```

In addition, this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/tutorials/quickstarter/developapp) shows how to develop an app for your device.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting other approaches. Are there any reasons why no console app functionality was included in Win10 IoT? Thanks again.